# How to use my email in outlook as a web form

Tags: asp.net, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

We have an Email notification system in our intranet web application. We have a requirement in which a request will be sent to a employee. We need to provide one option in the mail to accept or reject the request. Can we reflect their acceptance in the database of our web application.

Regards

Anand

Comment: Have a look at ews and its support for voting buttons in emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do the same thing and I found it to be better sending the email from the intranet with some text maybe from a resource file, but in the email add the unique id (or Guid) of the request to the end of a page on the intranet (~/AcceptReject.aspx?id=123456) and that page brings up the accept or reject buttons and that is then logged in the database.

This means you can tell by who is logged into the intranet and that they were the one who accepted or rejected the request - rather than their out of office forwarding it to the teams mailbox and someone else clicking one of the voting buttons etc.